# All permutations where 0/1 are added to each column of a dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, permutation

For each row of my dataframe (e.g. `A 1 2 3 4 5`), I want to generate all possible 2^5 row permutations where 0 or 1 were added to each column,  without duplicates.

i.e. I want to generate all length-5 permutations of [0,1] e.g. `[1,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0], [1,1,0,0,0]` as vectors, then add them to that row.

Desired output for the above example:

```
A 2 2 3 4 5  <<only first column added>>
A 1 3 3 4 5  <<only second column added>>
A 2 3 3 4 5  <<first and second columns added>>
```

Comment: please, attach your expected output example

Comment: Hi @NisheetPatel, please see the above edit

Comment: Are you sure there are 5! rows, I would think 2^5 is more accurate.

Comment: Your title says permutations but your example shows combinations. Which are you trying to do?

Comment: All possible combinations

Comment: So you want to generate all length-5 permutations of [0,1] e.g. `[1,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0], [1,1,0,0,0]` as vectors, then add them to your row.

Comment: Those are **permutations** (order matters), not combinations (order irrelevant, e.g. output is a set or sorted). I know it's hard but try not to confuse the two terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html) package to generate all possible combinations: 
itertools.product produces an iterable which you can cast to a list and then Dataframe (suggestions to prevent casting are very welcome)

```
x = pd.DataFrame(list((itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=5))))
x.head()
Out[46]: 
    0  1  2  3  4
0   0  0  0  0  0
1   0  0  0  0  1
2   0  0  0  1  0
3   0  0  0  1  1
4   0  0  1  0  0
5   0  0  1  0  1
6   0  0  1  1  0
7   0  0  1  1  1
```

in a next step you can just add your list to each row of the the dataframe

```
comb = x + [1,2,3,4,5]
comb.head()
Out[47]: 
    0  1  2  3  4
0   1  2  3  4  5
1   1  2  3  4  6
2   1  2  3  5  5
3   1  2  3  5  6
4   1  2  4  4  5
5   1  2  4  4  6
6   1  2  4  5  5
```